# Error in Eclipse..no resource found while retrieving the name

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed the Eclipse and sdk.while creating my first app I got error,its saying no resource found while retrieving the name 'theme.appcombat.light'.i have followed your soln that was given in previous post but it didn't work out.while importing appcompat folder there is many folder inside it with numbers as name. I am totally helpless pls help

Comment: you need to import appcompat , you can find it in 
"Path to SDK"\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

or try android studio, which makes these things easy